# converting nested list into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
b = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
c = {}
for i in range(len(b)):
    m = i[0]
    c[m] = i[1]
```

My goal is to make the nested list `b` into a dictionary. However, I keep getting an error saying

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try printing out `i` in your `for` loop, and you might see where the problem is.

Comment: o i see. thats what it means when it says int objects are not subscriptable. but why does the code in the second response work?

Comment: Use `dict(b)` here

Comment: @Peter the loop `for i in b` loops through each item of b and sets it to `i`, so the first item would be `['a', '1']`, second `['b', '2']`, etc. `for i in range(len(b))` loops through a range with length `b`, so `i` is 1, 2, 3. If in doubt, put in a `print` statement so you can see exactly what your iterator is. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
b = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
d={}
for i in b:
    d[i[0]]=i[1]
```

Comment: wow it worked. thats essentially what I thought I did but thank you so much!

Comment: sorry i had to delete my last response because it was too confusing. I also tried setting the index of each iteration as a dictionary key and value and that also worked.

Comment: but to answer your question, I do not know why my code is wrong.

Comment: You are iterating over the indexes of `b` not the elements of `b` so `for elem in b: elem[0]` is equivalent to `for index in range(len(b)): b[index][0]`. Note: you can unpack in this `for` loop, e.g. `for k, v in b: d[k] = v`

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain the main issue with your code.  But bottom line, best to use a dict comprehension:

```
{k:v for k, v in b}
# {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

Or just:

```
dict(b)
```

Your code as is will throw an error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

To understand why, try `for i in range(len(b)): print(i)`.  You'll see that your loop iteration values are just the index values of `b`, not the lists stored in `b`.

So doing `i[0]` won't work, since `i` is just an integer.  What you want is more like `b[i][0]`.  But there are easier ways to do that.

In particular, try instead: `for i in b: print(i)`.
You'll see that now your iterations are putting each list inside `b` into `i`, and then you can do `m = i[0]` as planned.  After that, your code will work, storing each dict value (`i[1]`) in each dict key (`m`):

```
for i in b: 
    m = i[0]
    c[m] = i[1]
```

Note: While it is convention to use `i` when keeping track of index values, it's not really best practice (for that same reason) to use `i` for other kinds of iteration values.  To avoid confusing your future self, use `x` or even `current_list` instead of `i` as your loop iterator name in situations like this.  (But really, I'd advise just using the simpler alternatives I started out with at the top of this post.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are attempting to index into an integer `i` as if it was a list. I think you meant `b[i][0]` (this says: give me the *0*-th item of the *i*-th item in `b`).

This is a little easier:

```
b = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
d = dict(b)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```